# G-streamer Deepstream Could not receive message (Parse error)

Tags: python, gstreamer, nvidia-deepstream

I am connecting multiple (10-30) rstp streams to a g-streamer pipeline using deepstream for object tracking and running inference (by using a muxer to batch the streams into one). However, the pipeline almost immediately crashes when the streams have all connected. There is a connection established, and then after a short period it crashes. These are the logs I get when the pipeline fails:

```
**PERF : FPS_0 (2.36)   FPS_1 (2.36)    FPS_2 (2.36)    FPS_3 (2.36)    FPS_4 (2.36)    FPS_5 (2.36)    FPS_6 (2.36)    FPS_7 (2.36)    FPS_8 (2.36)    FPS_9 (2.36)    FPS_10 (2.36)   FPS_11 (2.36)   FPS_12 (2.36)   
2023-08-11 15:10:12 jetson-1234 bus_call[1] ERROR Error: gst-resource-error-quark: Could not read from resource. (9): gstrtspsrc.c(5560): gst_rtspsrc_loop_interleaved (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstBin:source-bin-ip_camera_2/GstURIDecodeBin:uri-decode-bin/GstRTSPSrc:source:
Could not receive message. (Parse error)

2023-08-11 15:10:12 jetson-1234 app[1] INFO Exiting app

nvstreammux: Successfully handled EOS for source_id=1
nvstreammux: Successfully handled EOS for source_id=11
[NvMultiObjectTracker] De-initialized
```

The camera that fails in this instance is ip_camera_2 but it's a different one each time, and I have had the same model running indefinitely with one camera (including one that fails when I use lots of cameras). I don't know if it's related but I also see much lower FPS than I expect to.

I'm new to G-streamer and Deepstream so if someone could point me in the right direction it'd be much appreciated.

Platform info:

- Jetson AGX
- Deepstream 6.2
- Jetpack 5

Plugins

- Muxer: nvstreammux
- Source bins: uridecodebin (rtspt stream)
- Inference: nvinfer
- Tracker: nvtracker

Comment: Try to look at memory usage, It might be that there are not enought resources to process all the videos. What happens when you use, lets say 20, 15, 10 video sources?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Memory usage was ok in the end - the issue was network bandwidth. Nothing to do with the jetson. I switched the way that the cameras were connecting and these issues went away.